# django retrieving data from two model with foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I'm just new with django programming and I'm having this designed models

```
class Client(models.Model):
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    accountant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastname + ' ' + self.firstname + ' ' + self.middlename + ' | ' + str(self.accountant) + ' | ' + str(self.id)

    def get_absolute_url(self):    
        return reverse('home')

class Consultation(models.Model):
    accountant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    clientid = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    concern = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.clientid) + ' | ' + str(self.accountant)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('client_details.html')
```

and my problem is in views with this code

```
def ConsultationUpdateView(request, pk):
    consultation = Consultation.objects.filter(id=pk)
    client = Client.objects.filter(id=consultation.clientid)
    return render(request, 'client_consultationupdate.html', {'client':client, 'consultation':consultation})
```

First one is, as per checking with the retrieve "consultation" values it had this

```
<QuerySet [<Consultation: Chad Milky Sugar | will | 1 | will>]>
```

and there's no "concern" field in this queryset, is this why "concern" field value not appearing in my HTML page? If so how can I pass the concern field value to the page? (BTW, I'm working now with editing part that's why I need to pass the "concern" field value to the page)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}    
{% block title %}Update Concern{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class="form-group">
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <small for="concern">Concern</small>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Concern" name="concern" value="{{ concern }}">             
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Add</button>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

The second one, there is a problem with this line of code

```
client = Client.objects.filter(id=consultation.clientid)
```

where in error message says "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'clientid'". Is there a way to get the clientid value from consultation and be use to filter on my second filter?

Thank You in Advance...

Comment: change to, consultation = Consultation.objects.get(id=pk) client = Client.objects.filter(id=consultation.clientid.id) or no need Client.objects.filter(id=consultation.clientid), because consultation.clientid givesClient, then  instance, then {{consultation.concern}}

Comment: yes it error is correct  "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'clientid'" becuse only instance know the members do change to client = Client.objects.get(id=consultation.clientid)

Comment: Thank you very much giveJob, I give it a try and It finally works now..